# Glossy button (similar to UISegmentedControl) in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a grouped UITableView with a row per section. I would like the same effect as the UISegmentedControl button (glossy/3D-ish/Modern look). What's the best way to do this without tearing down my UITableView methods code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tear down the tableView methods code...
Just have to customize your tableViewCells. [Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) you can seen how it should be done.
You'll need a glossy background Image or draw it yourself in code dynamically (not recommended)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if I create one buttoned UISegmentedControls instead?

Comment: sure, add that one to the cell.contentView and remove every other thing (background view, labels, etc.) from the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `UIButton` and use it in your cells, or you can directly customize cell background view and text label to make it look like a button.
For customizing the background of the cell: [Setting background image of custom table view cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271274/setting-background-image-of-custom-table-view-cells)

You may also consider using a simple, ready-to-use [custom button component](http://www.binpress.com/app/glossy-button-for-ios/968). It also provides a custom cell that you can easily use in your tableviews.

Looks like:

[image]